# Can't save password for ssh

Tags: linux-mint, midnight-commander

Linux Mint 20.3

Midnight Commander hotlist file content:

```
  GROUP "Server"
    ENTRY "/sh://root@172.18.111.10/opt/server" URL "/sh://root:MYPASS@172.18.111.10/opt/server"
  ENDGROUP
```

As you can see I set password. But **every time** when I start MC an try to connect by ssh to remote server always prompt me about pass

Comment: No experience with MC, but could you perhaps use an SSH key to login instead of a password?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Yes, I can use SSH key. But how it help me?

Comment: If you use an ssh key, you don't longer need to provide a password when connecting to the remote server. At least when using ssh from the command line, not sure how MC handles that.